# Ruby on Rails 3 - retrieved data always zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

I can't find a working solution for the following piece of code:

```
  def search_last_rate
    self.rate  = Rate.find(:first, :select => "rateconverted", :conditions => ["dominant_id = ? and converted_id = ?", self.currency_bought_iso, self.currency_sold_iso], :order => 'ratedate, dateloaded, timeloaded DESC')
  end
```

When I execute this in the console I retrieve the appropriate value:

```
`=> #<Rate rateconverted: 0.8131>`
```

All columns are defined in MYSQL2 as an `decimal` but when I'm using it in the model and new html page it's always saving the value `0.0`.

Please advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decimal and integer are different in mysql. if u want the data to be numeric then use 'integer' in migrations else 'float'. checkout  [Decimal VS Int in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682115/decimal-vs-int-in-mysql)

Comment: I have read this and understand the context but don't know how to use this in the code which I have now. Also read [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063968/ruby-on-rails-string-decimal-or-float-for-price-field) and think I should keep using decimal.

Comment: (add_column :parts, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2). scale is the maximum digits on the right side of decimal point and precision on the left side of decimal point.

Comment: Where do I have to add this? In the migration file I have already done this for example the rate column. `t.decimal :rate, :precision => 12, :scale => 8`. This is the case for all influenced columns. Help is much appreciated because I'm stuck :(

Comment: is the rate getting displayed properly?

Comment: In the database it is, and via the console to. When it's stored in the value `self.rate` not and it's stored as shown as `0.0`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that self.rate is not an integer
2. Try

   self.rate  = Rate.find(:first, :select => "rateconverted", :conditions => ["dominant_id = ? and converted_id = ?", self.currency_bought_iso, self.currency_sold_iso], :order => 'ratedate, dateloaded, timeloaded DESC').to_f

Comment: Thanks for your help already :) I have tried the statement and receive the following error: NoMethodError (undefined method `to_f' for #<Rate:0x4a4e160>):