# Rails Decimal Calculations with funky output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying a few decimal calculations, in a Rails app, but am getting some weird results.

```
@pprice = item.price - (( item.price / 100 ) * promo.discount)

@pprice = item.price - promo.discount
```

Each value (item.price, promo.discount etc) is a decimal. However, when trying to calculate I get mixed results, none of them being the correct total. The results range from nil, 0.0 and -2.0 depending on whether I have .to_f included.

The first calculation is based on a percentage discount and the second on a straight money reduction.

I have performed the calculations in the view (to test) and they display correctly, but when they are moved over to the controller, I get the errors.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since u r converting the values to float, ur calculation results arent precise.
see [String, decimal, or float datatype for price field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063968/ruby-on-rails-string-decimal-or-float-for-price-field)

Comment: When I don't include a to_f I get, either, an undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (for the straight money reduction, or undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass for the percentage reduction calculation.

Comment: Yes, just did a bit more checking and I'm doing the calculations based on `item`, which does not exists until a subscription has been saved. I have moved this after the `@subscription.save` and it works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: never depend on float to give precise results. Always use BigDecimal.